# What is android.media.AudioTrack equivalent in flutter?

Tags: flutter, audiotrack

I want to use flutter for a musical application. In android SDK, I have worked with android.media.AudioTrack to produce sound. I couldn't use Mediaplayer and Soundpool for that purpose. Is there any class in flutter SDK like AudioTrack? I want to synthesis the sound samples with some audio processing.

Comment: Flutter lives in its own vm, it need to access system api through platform channels. https://flutter.io/platform-channels/ 

https://pub.dartlang.org/flutter/packages?q=audio

Comment: Correct, you need to use platform channels. I've had plenty of success generating audio in Dart and passing that through a channel to an `AudioTrack`. Out of an abundance of caution, I drop the generated audio into a buffer and have a thread read from that into the `AudioTrack`. However, if you gave your track a large enough buffer, I bet you could write directly to it from the method handler. One huge annoyance is that the standard method codec doesn't understand array of float 32, so you have to convert to bytes or doubles to cross the Dart/Java boundary.

Answer (score 0):

I found https://pub.dev/packages/sound_stream which using AudioTrack on android